# Using AVPlayer for streaming is slow

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I use AVPlayer for streaming mp3 file from the internet and it works really slow. Using profiler I found out, that it downloads entire file at first, and then starts playing. Is there any workaround for this?

Right now, I'm using this code

```
if let player = player {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)

    let item = AVPlayerItem(url: url)

    player.replaceCurrentItem(with: item)
} else {
    player = AVPlayer(url: url)
}
player?.play()
```

Things I've tried:

- move player?.play() to an observer, attached to *status* property of the item
- play around with properties *preferredForwardBufferDuration* and *preferredPeakBitRate*

All the time the result is downloading a whole audio file and only then start of playing.

Please note, the issue is - player starts to play ONLY after the whole file was downloaded, while I want it to stream mp3.

Comment: you can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813557/playing-stream-with-bad-internet-in-avplayer

Comment: try using: player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false

Comment: @Suen, yes! it plays before whole loading now. could you change your comment to an answer, so it could be more visible for others?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To play immediately you can try to set

```
player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false
```

Comment: Does not work for me, the AVPlayer is still downloading the whole video first and then starts the playback :(

Comment: this solution didn't fix the problem

Comment: when i add above line avplayer download whole video and then start play

Comment: If we keep automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling to true, It takes huge time to play a remote url. Then, What's the benefit of using it? I know what purpose it solves but loading time increases, which makes us setting it to false.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an observer to when the AVPlayer gets empty buffer:

```
[[self.tracksPlayer currentItem] addObserver:self 
                              forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty" 
                                 options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                                 context:nil];
```

And an observer so you can know when the AVPlayer buffered enough to keep up:

```
[[self.tracksPlayer currentItem] addObserver:self 
                              forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp" 
                                 options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew 
                                 context:nil];
```

Then just check for that in your KVO callback:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath 
                  ofObject:(id)object 
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change 
                   context:(void *)context {

if (object == [self.tracksPlayer currentItem] && 
  [keyPath isEqualToString:@"playbackBufferEmpty"]) {

  if ([self.tracksPlayer currentItem].playbackBufferEmpty) {

      NSLog(@"Buffer Empty"); 
  }
} else if (object == [self.tracksPlayer currentItem] && 
         [keyPath isEqualToString:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp"]) {


  if ([self.tracksPlayer currentItem].playbackLikelyToKeepUp) {

      NSLog(@"LikelyToKeepUp");
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, that I understand, how it can help me

Comment: Apple documentation says that playbackLikelyToKeepUp might be NO, even if playbackBufferFull is YES. As I understand, playbackLikelyToKeepUp is based on internet connection speed, not on amount of data in buffer.

Comment: still, I don't get, how it can help me. even if I know, that it can't play it yet, because of something, - how can I help it to start playing?