# Play remote wav audio

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, audio-streaming

I'm trying to play `wav` audio files from a remote URL, I was using this [StreamPlayer](https://github.com/pomin/StreamPlayer) library to play the remote audio file. However, It is not working for the `wav` formats, although it is working for `mp3`'s.

I tried the using the native `AVPlayer` in iOS, but it is waiting until the buffering finishes, which is taking a long time if I'm playing a large file. I tried the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42639917/3978588), but it didn't resolve the issue.

I have also tried using [this library](https://github.com/douban/DOUAudioStreamer) . I got it to load the file from the remote URL, but with weird interrupting while buffering.

I need suggestions for library that can play `wav` files from a remote URL, or any hint that may help me.

Answer (score 0):

The StreamPlayer library is based on the Audio Queue Services, which supports playing PCM (aka WAV) [according to the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/audio_queue_services?language=objc#overview).

It also [passes `self.fileType` to AudioFileStreamOpen](https://github.com/tuoxie007/audio-stream-player-objc/blob/155da879ab5bfb707bea034e7da3d06ff3ace829/AudioStreamPlayer/AudioStreamPlayer/HSUAudioStreamPlayer.m#L318), and it is initialized to `kAudioFileWAVEType` if the URL ends with ".wav".

So if mp3 streaming works for you, it should not be difficult to debug the library code and tweak it to support wav if that's not working.

Comment: That StreamPlayer library is current as of Xcode 5 (i.e. 5 years ago now?).  Is there anything more current/supported than that?

Comment: If you ask me, I would just learn and use Audio Queue Services directly :)